# IIS 7.5 returning a 404 for one MVC route, but only when deployed

Tags: iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc

I have a site that is working fine on my local dev machine.  When I run everything in IIS Express, the site is working fine.  However, when i deploy my app to production, everything but one route is working.  That one MVC route is returning a 404 error.

I turned on Failed Request Tracing and have the trace file.  All i can see in it is that there is a warning on the "Module Set Response Error Status" and it says it came from the ManagedPipelineHandler.

There's nothing I can find unique about this route.  Everything I can find says it should work, but for some reason it doesn't.

The Failed Request Tracing reads like a set of stereo instructions.  I'm not sure what I should be looking for.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try adding following code in your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<!-- rest of config -->
</system.webServer>
```

2) Make sure that your application is running under ASP.Net 4.0 integrated pipeline mode. If not, set this application pool to integrated pipeline mode and recycle it once.